# Simple animation puzzle game development

Tags: game-engine, gamekit

I want to develop a simple "guess next frame" game. Basically, the game will show a picture of a stock chart with the right side of chart hidden (the future price). When player ready, he will guess price up or down, and next hidden part of future price is revealed. If correct, he gets points... something like that. Simple game.

Is there any existing game code and framework that I can use to develop this? I am totally new in game development. 
I suspect there is game engine or framework available to make this type of game easy and fast.

Would be best if it can run on mobile phones OS and PC

Can anyone suggest ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple javascript game should do the trick. There is just some small logic involved which isnt too complicated. If you want to overdo it, you'd probably use a [mvc framework](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/). You could probably though just do a simple jQuery/HTML mixture with a small server backend for the charts that you will be presenting.